# Обработчик прерываний BIOS GNU Assembler

Tags: linux, ассемблер, bios, gnu

Пишу загрузчик на языке Ассемблера (`GNU Assembler`, синтаксис `AT&T`). Необходимо написать для него обработчик прерываний `BIOS`.

На просторах интернета нашёл, что для того, чтобы сделать свою "функцию" обработчиком, необходимо вызвать подфункцию `0x25` прерывания `0x21`, указав в регистре `al` желаемый номер для своего прерывания, в регистре `ds` - сегмент, в регистре `dx` - сдвиг на свою функцию относительно этого сегмента.

Пусть есть программа:

```
.code16
.text
.globl _start

_start:
    jmp _boot

.macro mWriteString str
    leaw  \str, %si
    call   WriteString
.endm

.func WriteString
WriteString:
    lodsb
    orb     %al, %al
    jz     WriteString_done

    movb    $0xe, %ah
    movw    $9, %bx
    int    $0x10

    jmp    WriteString

    WriteString_done:
    retw
.endfunc

msgHello: .asciz "Hello in my boot loader!\n\r"

myInterrupt:
    mWriteString msgHello
    iret

_boot:
    cli
    movw $0x07C0, %ax
    movw %ax, %ds
    movw %ax, %ss
    movw %ax, %sp
    sti

    mov $0x25, %ah
    mov $0x65, %al
    mov myInterrupt, %dx
    int $0x21

    int $0x65

    . = _start + 510
    .byte 0x55
    .byte 0xAA
```

По прерыванию на экран должна выводиться строка с текстом "`Hello in my boot loader!`". Но, к сожалению, эта строка не выводится, откуда я делаю вывод, что прерывание не вызывается.

Прошу помощи в приведении кода к рабочему состоянию!

Comment: Вы указали в вопросе, что используете ассемблер GAS под Unix. Тогда зачем вам в коде 0x21 прерывание MS-DOS? Насколько я знаю, в Unix всегда использовалось 0x80 прерывание для системных вызовов.

Comment: @Nikita ага, самого смущало. Но я на примеры опирался, а в них поголовно 0x21. К слову, 0x80 не работает.

Comment: Вы эту программу откуда пытаетесь запускать ? Прямо из ОС linux ? я вот вижу у вас в конце сигнатура загрузочного сектора. может вы делаете это в загрузчике и запускаете под эиулятором x86 ? эти сведения надо указать в вопросе

Comment: @Mike да, это действительно код загрузочного сектора, и я запускаю диск через эмулятор. Сейчас укажу.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я в real mode запускаю. Сейчас поправлю вопрос, чтобы не возникало непоняток

Comment: Когда вы запускаете что то как загрузчик, он грузится _вместо_ операционной системы. А прерывание `int 21h` это сервис ОС MS-DOS, а никакого DOS у вас нет. вам надо менять вектор прерываний руками, прямо в таблице векторов в самом начале оперативной памяти.посмотрите примеры например тут http://perscom.ru/index.php/2012-01-20-09-29-00/29-i8259/99-2012-01-18-09-05-15

Comment: @Mike понял, спасибо. Попробую - отпишу, что получилось.

Comment: А ещё не забудьте, что весь Ваш код должен остаться в памяти до перезагрузки (ну или пока ещё кто не переназначит вектор прерывания), т.е. следует заблокировать участок памяти с кодом (и его данными, включая свой стек, если будет) от посягательств других процессов. Если же кто-то в этот блок памяти влезет грязными ногами, то первый же вызов прерывания скорее всего отправит систему в состояние перманентной комы, если не хуже.

Comment: @Akina как можно реализовать блокировку памяти?

Comment: В реальном режиме обычно обработчик размещают в "верхних" блоках памяти (640 кб) и корректируют объём оперативной памяти (0040h:0013h). Правда, в этом случае квант выделения - 1 кбайт. С другой стороны, обработчику неплохо бы озаботиться собственным стеком (ну мало ли...), и тогда 1 кбайт при объёме кода в полкило - вполне нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добился положительных результатов. Особая благодарность [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike) за очень полезную ссылку. Вот что получилось:

```
.code16
.text
.globl _start

_start:
    jmp _boot

.macro mWriteString str
    leaw  \str, %si
    call   WriteString
.endm

.func WriteString
WriteString:
    lodsb
    orb %al, %al
    jz WriteString_done

    movb $0xe, %ah
    movw $9, %bx
    int $0x10

    jmp WriteString

    WriteString_done:
    retw
.endfunc

msgHello: .asciz "Hello in my boot loader!\n\r"

myInterrupt:
    mWriteString msgHello
    hlt

// Смещение вектора 0x65
.set off_x65, 0x65*4
old_off_x65: .long 0
old_seg_x65: .long 0

_boot:
    cli

    movw $0x07C0, %ax
    movw %ax, %ds
    movw %ax, %ss
    movw %ax, %sp

    movw $0x0, %ax
    movw %ax, %es

    // Сохраняем старый вектор
    movw %es:off_x65, %ax
    movw %ax, old_off_x65
    movw %es:off_x65 + 2, %ax
    movw %ax, old_seg_x65

    // Записываем новый вектор
    movw $myInterrupt, %ax
    movw %ax, %es:off_x65
    push %ds
    pop %ax
    movw %ax, %es:off_x65+2

    sti

    int $0x65

    . = _start + 510
    .byte 0x55
    .byte 0xAA
```